# Best solution to allow external developers access our internal Git server?

Tags: networking, security, git

My company outsources a lot of software development. Usually the suppliers manage the source code until the application is finished and then hand it over to us. This has obvious downsides: (1) we have no control over who has access to the code during development; (2) we are unable to conduct code reviews or static analysis before the end of development. The solution would be to have a Git server in our company and allow external developers connect to it. This would enable proper access management on our side. However, the only network segment that can be accessed directly from the outside is the DMZ. I don't like the idea of having sensitive data such as source code in the DMZ. We could put the server in an internal segment, which cannot be accessed directly. Then we would need to provide external developers with VPN access, which means managing their identities in our AD, or we could configure a rule on the FW, but that would violate network segmentation rules.

Can you think of a better solution? Have you seen any solution of this problem and was it convenient? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We used to host our own source control server in the office. The development team grew in size, and so did the administrative effort required to maintain the server. Also we started using freelance developers working outside the office.

In the end we moved source control to a external hosted git hosting. There are many such services (e.g. SourceForge, BitBucket, Gitlab, GitHub) available.

Regarding security having external developers access source projects is a concern. Often developers are lax when it comes to storing secrets in source code that would be useful to a hacker.

There is the option of secure git hosting (there is the free and open source [Keybase](https://keybase.io/)) or use a git helper which encrypts files before pushing to the server such as-:

[git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt)

> **git-crypt** enables transparent encryption and decryption of files in a
>   git repository.  Files which you choose to protect are encrypted when
>   committed, and decrypted when checked out.  git-crypt lets you freely
>   share a repository containing a mix of public and private content.

or [git-secret](https://github.com/sobolevn/git-secret)

> **git-secret** is a bash tool which stores private data inside a git repo.
>   git-secret encrypts files with permitted users' public keys, allowing
>   users you trust to access encrypted data using pgp and their secret
>   keys.